# Question about The Extreme Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The following is a proof of The Extreme Value Theorem in my textbook:

By the Boundedness Theorem, we know that $f([a,b])$ has an upper bound, and thus, by the completeness property of $\mathbb{R}$, it has a least upper bound. Call this least upper bound $M$. We need to show that $M$ is the image of some point $c \in [a,b]$. We will prove this by contradiction, so assume that $M$ is not in the image of $f([a,b])$. Then the function $g(x) = M -f(x)$ is continuous and strictly positive on all of $[a,b]$. But more than that: because $M$ is the least upper bound, we know that $g^{-1}((0,\epsilon)) \ne \emptyset$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, because otherwise $M-\epsilon$ would be an upper bound for $f([a,b]).$

Since $g(x) \ne 0$ on $[a,b]$, the function $h(x) = 1/g(x)$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$. However, $h(x)$ is unbounded, since for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $x$ such that $g(x) < \epsilon$, and hence $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is not an upper bound for $h$. But the unboundedness of $h$ contradicts the Boundedness Theorem.

Therefore, $M$ must be in $f([a,b])$, as desired.

I wanted to know if the reason that we say that $g^{-1}((0,\epsilon)) \ne \emptyset$ instead of, say, $g^{-1}((0,\epsilon]) \ne \emptyset$, is because we don't want to have the possibility that $h(x) =\frac{1}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$?

Comment: When you take the limit of $\epsilon \to 0$ in $(0,\epsilon]$ what happens?

Comment: @stochs: h goes to infinity?

Comment: I mean what happens to the set $(0,\epsilon]$

Comment: @stochs: The set becomes a set with its only member being 0?

Comment: Can 0 belong to the set? It is a left open interval

Comment: @stochs: I'm not really sure where you're going with this. But anyways, no, 0 can't belong to the set.

Comment: Then is the statement $g^{-1}(0,\epsilon]\neq \emptyset$ true as $\epsilon \to 0$?